# Rails_admin has_many association shows links to object not nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am developing an application using ruby on rails 3.2.16 with Rails_admin panel.

There are two models: `Person`, and `PersonMetadatum` (the name of the model `PersonMetadatum` because of this: [link](http://blog.luckyus.net/2009/02/03/rails-inflection-of-metadata-and-data/). But that's not the point. Below you can find the associations:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :person_metadata_attributes
  has_many :person_metadata
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person_metadata, :allow_destroy => true
end

class PersonMetadatum < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :key, :person_id, :value, :person_metadatum
  attr_accessible :person_attributes, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible *attribute_names, :as => :admin
  belongs_to :person
end
```

When in `rails_admin` when I just want to list all fields of model I got something like this below:

```
Person metadata PersonMetadatum #3, PersonMetadatum #12, PersonMetadatum #13, PersonMetadatum #14, and PersonMetadatum #2
```

Of course in `rails_admin` it is done like that:

```
config.model Person do
  field :person_metadata
  field :name
end

config.model PersonMetadatum do
  field :id
  field :key
  field :value
  field :person_id
end
```

But I don't want to have links to objects, but I want to have nested form.
What can be the problem?
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Which page would you like to have a nested form on? On the edit page of the `Person` model?

Comment: That's right! But when I am doing like that with this settings there is only a list of names with links to `PersonMetadatum` objects